# Как правильно применить метод класса?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Я описал класс, который загружает данные с сервера в dataframe и обрабатывает их. Вот мой код (без импорта библиотек):

```
class Save(Data):
        def __init__(self, server, database, username, driver, group=None):
            super().__init__(server, database, username, driver)
            self.group = group

        def get_all_goods(self):
            goods_table = pd.read_sql_query(f''' SELECT [p_1], [p_2] 
                                  FROM [table] WHERE [group] = '{self.group}' ''',
                                  self.hndl)
            return goods_table

        def data_preprocessing(self):
            data_prepared = self.get_all_goods()
            data_prepared['desc'] = data_prepared[['p_1', 'p_2']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
            return data_prepared

        @staticmethod
        def data_cleaning(str):
            words = []
            str = re.sub(r"(\w*(\.\w*))", ' ', str)
            str = re.sub(r"\d*\_\d*", ' ', str)
            for i in re.split('[;,.,\n,\s,:,-,+,(,),=,/,«,»,@,!,?,",_,*]',str):
                if len(i) > 1:
                    words.append(i)
            return words

        def data_morphy(self, text):
            morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
            tokens = [morph.parse(token)[0].normal_form for token in self.data_cleaning(text) if token != ' ']
            tokens = list(dict.fromkeys(tokens))
            text = ' '.join(tokens)
            return text

        def data_final(self):
            data_f = self.data_preprocessing()
            data_f['desc'] = data_f['desc'].apply(lambda x: self.data_morphy(x))
            return data_final
```

Когда я вызываю метод `data_final` код не выполняется в том смысле, что нет сообщений об ошибке, но и выполнение не останавливается. Методы `get_all_goods` и `data_preprocessing` работают нормально. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того чтобы вернуть DataFrame `data_f` в методе `data_final()`, вы возвращаете ссылку на сам метод / функцию `data_final`.

Замените:

```
        return data_final
```

на:

```
        return data_f
```